# Поддерживает ли C# синонимы?

Tags: c#

Есть ли аналог `#define` из C++ в C#?

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: И про заголовок не надо забывать

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives

Comment: Так всё-таки "синонимы" или "define"? Синонимы в C# есть, макроподстановок в виде define - нет.

Comment: Слава Асгарду - нет. Такого говнокода на C# мы никогда не увидим. Как-то попросили разобраться в коде на C++ для внесения изменений, а он состоит больше чем на 50% из подстановок defin'ами.

Answer (score 1):

Объявление констант

```
C++
#define MAX_VALUE 2000000000
↓
C#
public const int MAX_VALUE = 2000000000;
```

Замена имен типов

```
C++
#define str std::string;
↓
C#
using str = System.String;
```

Comment: в c# нет аналога `#define` из c/c++. `#define` позволяет многократно использовать код, в c# `#define` нужен только для объявления "констант" (тут они даже значения не содержат). и кто через `#define` типы определяет? есть же `typedef`.

Comment: Нужно бы объяснить, что синонимы в C# без надобности.

Comment: @return Можно с помощью define это определят типы? Теоретически, можно. Я объяснил? Я объяснил. А кто это так делает - не мое дело.

Comment: @МаксимФисман мне кажется вы ничего не объяснили. просто сказали, что так можно, хотя это явно плохая практика. в c# отказались от `#define` дабы избежать говнокода, а пример с `#define str std::string` и есть говнокод

Comment: @return Мой ответ дан на **поставленный** вопрос. Кардинально другой ответ на поставленный вопрос дать невозможно. Да, это пример *плохого* кода, **но** об этом вопрошает вопрошающий. Если хотите, вы можете проголосовать за закрытие вопроса. Я пока (пока!) не голосовал за вопрос ни в какую сторону, также не голосовал за закрытие, я лишь **дал** ответ на **поставленный** вопрос. Также не рекомендую вам забывать о полном праве написать свой ответ. Вы, как я понял, уже проголосовали за мой ответ, исполнив свой "долг" перед сайтом. Чего еще может быть нужно (риторический вопрос)?

Comment: Я бы добавил пару ссылок на документацию: [using directive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive), [extern alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) - и тогда ответ меня бы полностью устроил.